# Firestore rules access to parent document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So i'm making an app with a friends system and trying to set up rules for firebase to handle reads & writes if the users is friends or not.
I'm very stuck at a particular call that i just don't have any idea on how to make.
My firestore is structured as follows:

users/userUID/places/documentsofplaces

each userdocument have some fields of the usual information, name, username, etc. and an array of friendsUID.
I have managed to get the first part down, that a user can only read and write if it's UID matches the documentUID, and looking in the friendslist a friend can only read but not write.
The next part, in the places collection, just throws me off, how can i get the parent document and compare the userUID to a UID in the friendslist?
This is what i have so far:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
        // Allow write and read if user, and read if friend
      allow write: if isUser(userId);
      allow read: if isUser(userId) || isFriend();

      function isUser(userId) {
        return (request.auth.uid == userId);
        }

      function isFriend() {
            return (request.auth.uid in resource.data.friendsList);
        }

    }
    match /users/{userId}/places/{documents} {
        allow write: if isUser(userId);
        allow read: if isUser(userId) || isFriend(userId);

        function isUser(userId) {
        return (request.auth.uid == userId);
        }

      function isFriend(userId) {
            return (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/userId.resource.data.friendsList));
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document `get()` should look more like this:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.friendsList
```

You have to use variables with `$(var)` notation inside the document path.  [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) returns a Resoruce object with a data property.  I suggest reading over the documentation for [accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved it! (and kinda good to see i wasn't that far off, atleast logic wise)